# PHP save PNG from base64 *rgba* string

Tags: php, image, png, base64, jpeg

I'm wondering if there is someone who can help me with this, i'm sending an image from my  windows phone c# to php and i want to save the image.

The data connection works and i can receive the POST value 
see: http://posttestserver.com/data/2014/01/23/19.41.40516059397 for the information the server receives.

i now want to save this base64 encoded ***RGBA*** string to a png or jpg (i would prefer png but i dont need the alpha value).

this is the code i have server side

```
//getimagecontents  
$data = base64_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
//create an image from string
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
  //add an header for the image
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  //save the image
  imagepng($im, 'upload/test.png');
  imagedestroy($im);
  echo "it worked!";
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me with this coz it's keeping me up all night :(

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are receiving the data. If yes. then try once without base64_decode and upload directory is created in place that is where your image will be saved. If it is not created, you can not save image.

You should have received warnings in both cases indicating the problem. If this your dev environment, turn the warnings reporting on in php.ini or your script.

Another thing, why are you sending header for image when only you intend to save it to file system.

Answer (score 0):

The image i was sending was too big for the server to handle...

As it was send as a RAW file...

converted it to a png and now works like a charm